# Question/Answer and Comment functions don't seem to work properly across sites

Tags: bug

I noticed that question/answer functionality seems to be broken on all sites lately. As far as I know, I haven't turned off scripts (unless my latest Firefox update did that without my knowledge, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the options to turn it on/off). I don't currently have any plug-ins that disable scripts. What I'm seeing is the following:

For questions/answers:

- The preview window isn't working, and there are no formatting
  buttons.
- The similar question search doesn't happen when typing in
  the Title field.
- No tag suggestions appear when typing in the Tags
  field.

Note that the above doesn't happen when I'm editing an existing question/answer.

For comments:
- Clicking o the Add comment link just takes me to the top of the page.

**Edit** I guess it's been fixed and this question can be <s>closed</s> put on hold.

Comment: You are unfortunately just a bit late to the party.